# Clarifications needed for a crash using NSArray, blocks and Manual Reference Counting

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I need some clarifications on a crash I'm encountering using `NSArray`, blocks and Manual Reference Counting. My goal is to store blocks on a collection (`NSArray` in this case) in order to reuse them in the future.

I've setup a small sample to replicate the issue. In particular, I have a class `Item` that looks like the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^MyBlock)();

@interface Item : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithBlocks:(NSArray*)blocks;

@end

#import "Item.h"

@interface Item ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *blocks;

@end

@implementation Item

- (instancetype)initWithBlocks:(NSArray*)blocks
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (MyBlock block in blocks) {
            [temp addObject:[[block copy] autorelease]];
        }

        _blocks = [temp copy];            
    }
    return self;
}
```

The usage is described below (I'm using in the app delegate).

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    __block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    MyBlock myBlock1 = ^() {
        [weakSelf doSomething1];
    };

    MyBlock myBlock2 = ^() {
        [weakSelf doSomething1];
    };

    NSArray *blocks = @[myBlock1, myBlock2];

    // As MartinR suggested the code crashes even
    // if the following line is commented
    Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithBlocks:blocks];
}
```

If I run the app, it crashes with an **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** (note that I've already enabled *All Exceptions* breakpoints). In particular, the app stops in the main.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

**Note**: As suggested by Ken Thomases, if you use bt command on llvm console, you are to see the back trace. In this case it shows the following:

> -[__NSArrayI dealloc]

If I comment the `[weakSelf doSomethingX];` it works without crashes (it does not mean that is correct).

Modifying the code a little bit like the following, all runs ok.

```
// Item does not do anymore the copy/autorelease dance
// since used in the declaration of the blocks
- (instancetype)initWithBlocks:(NSArray*)blocks
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _blocks = [blocks retain];

    }
    return self;
}
```

and

```
__block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

MyBlock myBlock1 = [[^() {
    [weakSelf doSomething1];
} copy] autorelease];

MyBlock myBlock2 = [[^() {
    [weakSelf doSomething1];
} copy] autorelease];

NSArray *blocks = @[myBlock1, myBlock2];

Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithBlocks:blocks];
```

What is the point here? I think I'm missing something but I don't know what.

**Update 1**

Ok. I'll try to recap my thoughts based on the comments with @Martin R and @Ken Thomases.

A block, by default, is created on stack if a `copy` message is not sent to it (ARC does this for us) in order to move it on the heap. So, the situation in this case is the following. I create an `autorelease` array and I add two blocks where `retain` is called in a implicit manner. When the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method finishes is execution, the blocks, since created on the stack (they are `automatic` variables) disappear. In a later moment, the array called `blocks` will be released since has been marked as `autorelease`. So, it will crash since it will send a `release` object to blocks that do not exist anymore.

**So, my question is the following: What does it mean to send a `retain` message to a block that is on the stack? Why the array is the source of the crash (see the back trace)?** In other words, since a block is on the stack, will it bump the retain count of it? And when it goes out of scope? In addiction, why if I comment the `[weakSelf doSomething1]` line the code works without problems? Not very clear to me this part.

Comment: Are you really still using manual reference counting?

Comment: Yes, since I have a legacy project and I cannot enable ARC for now. In addition, I would understand something that I'm missing in the following setup. Thanks @Martin R.

Comment: I assume that the problem is in `NSArray *blocks = @[myBlock1, myBlock2];`. As in your Item class, blocks must be copied when added to a collection: `NSArray *blocks = @[[[myBlock1 copy] autorelease], [[myBlock2 copy] autorelease]];`

Comment: Where does it crash? What is the backtrace and what line of your code does the debugger show?

Comment: @KenThomases it crashes in main but no trace is displayed.

Comment: Xcode is probably collapsing the stack trace. Make sure the slider below the stack trace is dragged all the way to the right. Also, when Xcode has your program stopped at the crash, you can type "bt" at the "lldb" prompt in the console view.

Comment: @MartinR Yes. But I cannot understand why since the scope set for the blocks is defined. The 2nd snippet is within the `didFinish...` method of the application delegate.

Comment: Martin is probably right. The array literal `@[ ... ]` effectively creates an autoreleased array. The crash is probably happening when it is eventually released, which is after the scope in which the blocks were defined and thus after they have been deallocated. `-release` is being sent to garbage objects at that point. You could try creating that array with `+alloc` and `-initWithObjects:` and then explicitly releasing it, although that's not a guarantee that it doesn't live on in an autorelease pool.

Comment: It crashes even if you omit the `Item *item = ...` statement, so the problem is unrelated to the Item class. And the backtrace shows `-[__NSArrayI dealloc]` which is probably the deallocation of the `blocks`array (as Ken also suspected in the last comment).

Comment: @MartinR I've updated my question based on the comments with you.

Comment: @KenThomases I've updated my question based on the comments with you.

Comment: Maybe @bbum could say something on it ;)

Comment: I suspect that `-retain` and `-release` or no-ops on a block that is still on the stack, since they can't possibly affect the actual lifetime of the object. Similar to sending them to string literals (`@"..."`), which have static lifetime.

Comment: Regarding commenting out `[weakSelf doSomething1]`… I suspect — I'm doing a lot of speculating on this thread ;) — that empty blocks are recognized by the compiler and all resolve to a singleton provided by the runtime. Such a singleton would not live on the stack but have static lifetime and would thus never be deallocated. You could compare the block pointers of two variables pointing to nominally distinct empty blocks to check. Also, blocks which just logged a simple string would presumably not work like this and so would still cause the crash while eliminating the weak variable as a cause.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you very much for your support. I have one last gap. Why the crash? The autorelease pool sends a `release` message to the array, ok. Then the array sends a `release` message to its children, that are blocks (where a `retain` has been called to each of them with no effect). So, what does it mean to send a `release` to the children of the array? What they are? Dangling pointers?

Comment: Yes, they are dangling pointers. Somewhere within its internals, `NSArray` (or the concrete subclass) keeps pointers to the objects it contains. In the case of a block on the stack, the pointer is to somewhere on the stack. After that stack frame is exited, the pointer is dangling. It points to memory that is no longer a valid object and will be reused for the stacks of other call trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sticking an object from the stack into an autoreleased array. *BOOM* ensues.

Consider:

```
typedef void(^MyBlock)();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
          NSObject *o = [NSObject new];
          MyBlock myBlock1 = ^() {
            [o doSomething1];
          };
          NSLog(@"o %p", o);
          NSLog(@"b %p", myBlock1);
          NSLog(@"b retain %p", [myBlock1 retain]);
          NSLog(@"b copy %p", [myBlock1 copy]);
          NSLog(@"s %p", ^{});
          sleep(1000000);
        }
}
```

Compiled/run as -i386 (because the #s are smaller and more obvious):

```
a.out[11729:555819] o 0x7b6510f0
a.out[11729:555819] b 0xbff2dc30
a.out[11729:555819] b retain 0xbff2dc30
a.out[11729:555819] b copy 0x7b6511a0
a.out[11748:572916] s 0x67048
```

Since the object is at 0x7b, we can assume that is the heap.   0xb is really high memory and, thus, the stack.

The `retain` doesn't cause a `copy` (because doing so would have invariably led to leaks) and `retain` on a stack based object is meaningless.

---

If you change the `[o doSomething1];` to `[nil doSomething1];` then that becomes a static block and that lives in readonly mapped memory (readonly-executable pages from the mach-o's TEXT segment) and, thus, there is no allocation to deallocate and retain/release/autorelease are no-ops.

As you can see, the static block ended up around 0x67048 (this number may change from run to run, btw, for a variety of reasons.  Low in memory.

In fact, because of the sleep(), we can run vmmap against the a.out process and see:

```
==== Writable regions for process 11772
REGION TYPE              START - END     [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
__DATA                 00067000-00068000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ZER  /tmp/a.out
```

That is, the static block was in the first 4K segment of mapped writable regions from the mach-o file. Note that this doesn't mean the code is in that writable region (SECURITY HOLE if it were).  The code is in the TEXT segment mapped into the readable regions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Really appreciated. When you say *If you change the [o doSomething1]; to [nil doSomething1]; then that becomes a static block*, what do you mean with **static block**? Do you use it as a generic term to highlight that the block is not capturing any reference from the outer scope? Thanks ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted *static block* is like *static data*.  Same as using `@"foobar"` in your code;  if the compiler determines that something cannot, can never ever, change at runtime, then it will generally layout all the static information into some set of pages of memory within the executable that are marked up such that they look like objective-c classes, but are never allocated/deallocated, but simply mapped from the executable.  This is obviously fast.  And efficient.  The most common examples is `NSCFConstantString`.  Instances are a subclass of `NSString`.

Comment: @flexaddicted Oh -- and the compiler version, targeted architecture and/or optimization level may subtly change behaviors.